# Blank plot when using WorkingPrecision

Tags: plotting

I have the following code:

`Inv=WeierstrassInvariants[{1,I/3}]`

`Plot[Re[WeierstrassP[2*x + 1 + I/3, Inv]], {x, 0, 1/2}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 10]`

and I have completely blank plots.  Increasing the value of WorkingPrecision also doesn't change anything.  To the contrary, not using WorkingPrecision produces a plot.  Is there something I'm overlooking here?  I can use WorkingPrecision to plot simple functions, but I have yet to get it to work with Weierstrass-$\wp$ despite lots of work.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: But what are you trying to achieve with your setting of `WorkingPrecision`, especially since you are *reducing* it from the default?

Comment: @MarcoB I had no idea I was reducing it.  Is it because I don't have any decimals in the input?  Sorry, I'm completely new to even basic numerics.

Comment: For a starter, take a look at this tutorial: [Control the Precision and Accuracy of Numerical Results](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ControlThePrecisionAndAccuracyOfNumericalResults.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Inv = WeierstrassInvariants[{1, I/3}];
Plot[Re[N[WeierstrassP[2*x + 1 + I/3, Inv], 100]], {x, 0, 1/2}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Right, that's precisely what I get too but that's without using WorkingPrecision.  With WorkingPrecision, I get nothing.

Comment: @spietro See edit